# Keras Layers In Multiclass Classification Problem

Tags: python, keras, artificial-intelligence, tf.keras, keras-layer

I am doing a multiclass classification problem and my model is as follows

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(50, input_dim = 561, activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Dense(100, activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Dense(150, activation = 'softmax'))
model.add(Dense(75, activation = 'softmax')) 
model.add(Dense(50, activation = 'softmax'))
model.add(Dense(6, activation = 'softmax')) 

model.compile(loss = 'categorical_crossentropy', optimizer = 'adam', metrics = ['accuracy'])
print(model.summary())
```

and `model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=80, batch_size=10)` to compile the model

When I run it I am getting this error:

> Shapes (None, 1) and (None, 6) are incompatible

Any one can guide my how to solve this?

Comment: can you show the sizes of x_train and y_train ?

Comment: You did not one-hot encode your labels.

Comment: @BestDogeStackoverflow X_train size is (10269,561) and Y_train size is (18,561)

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy my dataset is [link](https://www.kaggle.com/c/uci-har) UCI-HAR  dataset so i don't think there is need for one-hot encoding in it.

Comment: If you are doing classification, you need to one-hot encode the labels, that is required by the categorical cross-entropy loss. And more importantly, we cannot guess why you think this is not required.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy ok so i need to do one-hot encoding for all the columns?

Comment: No, only the labels.